Framework / build setup for React-based PWA?
I'm new to building Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) and looking for advice on a good setup for a React-based PWA of medium complexity. The PWA functionality that interests me are offline caching/storage of the app and its data, push notifications, and the ability to launch like a regular app once added to a mobile home screen. However, it would also be nice if it performed well when accessed as a normal website.
Seems like the normal-website-access use cases are best served by Next.js and Remix, while the offline access might be better-suited to Create React App or Vite. How should I be thinking about this?

You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pwa, it gives you the ability for very fine-grained control and also has very good out-of-the box functionality like offline and caching for the normal website that you want.

Excellent. Does that mean you would advocate NOT going with Next.js or Remix here?

I like Next a lot and wouldn't be advocating against it, but you also have to use a package to make life easy with the pwa, https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa this works for next well, it uses workbox under the hood just like vite-pwa too. So scaffolding with plain Vite or Next will work just fine either way.

Can recommend next-pwa. It's seamless for most of the things. Only bit of hassle for few things
